# Start raspbmc to commandline immediately

Tags: boot, raspbmc

I have the following problem: I messed up the network settings on my raspberry pi (which is running raspbmc) and now I don't have any access to it anymore. I have a wireless keyboard attached to the pi and during the start it shows ^[ when I press esc. Once XBMC is started, it doesn't react to anything I do with the keyboard. I also tried to plug in a mouse (with cable) but XBMC doesn't show me a mouse pointer so there's also nothing I can do. Unfortunately I also disabled CEC, so I can't even use my remote do do anything anymore. At the moment, I also don't have a wired keyboard available.

Is there still a possibility to access my pi?
For example:

- Is there a way to access the network.conf on the SD-Card with another computer (which is running windows)?
- Is there a keyboard shortcut which I can press during startup to start to a console instead of XBMC?
- Do you maybe have other ideas?

EDIT:
So I realized that my Synology-NAS has a SD-card reader. I thus was able to access the network configuration (etc/network/interfaces) on the SD-card. I even could repair the filesystem after I unsafely removed it. However, it didn't solve my problem. Seems like there went something wrong when I installed an additional WIFI-driver. I'm not sure if I could also remove this driver installation while accessing the SD-card on the NAS, but I probably go for a new install now. Looks like that will take less time and I can then just install BerryBoot and have multiple os on the pi for the future.

Answer (score -2):

You could even download a live version of Ubuntu and pop that onto a USB stick to use for its handy dandy compatibility. Then edit the file from there, easy... right?
Also you could try pressing CTRL + C and see if this helps.